# Where does the MOSFET body diode come from?

Tags: mosfet, body-diode

Where does the body diode in a MOSFET come from? I understand that its built in and an intrinsic part of the MOSFET. All illustrations of a MOSFET that I've seen depict the structure as two diodes back to back but non hint at where the diode comes from.

[image: typical MOSFET structure]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1DuG9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To be more accurate, in a typical power U-mosfet structure in use today [aka trench mosfet], this body diode is a [PIN diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIN_diode):

[image]

Image from [this textbook](https://books.google.com/books?id=ujjSQqrJStwC&pg=PA400).

Answer (score 0):

It's a result of tying the body terminal to the source terminal during manufacture. Note that the gate has *no* physical connection to the body as is implied in the diode schematic.

Comment: How does the body get tied to the source during manufacture?

Comment: As part of the metalization layer.

Answer (score 0):

The FET needs a semiconductor for the current to flow in. For an n-channel enhancement device, this needs to be p-type (so that an n-channel can be induced in it with a + gate voltage). Since the S & D are necessarily n-type, and need to be constructed in the body, a N-P diode is necessarily formed.